# How to group files according to formats in folder structure in iOS app?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I'm trying to make an app where I can group different files in their respective folders from two accessed servers. For example all pictures from two servers should be in Picture folder and all music files in Music folder of the app.

As I have to access all the files from the server how could I group all the files in above mentioned folders.

Any suggestions how to initiate from above situation

Answer (score 1):

Generally interactions with the app's sanboxed file system are done via the NSFileManager class.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html

That class allows you to move, copy, delete, etc... You'll likely want to use it to first create your two directories, then use it to save files into those directories as needed.